# How to create an assignFirst method with Nodes in a BinarySearchTree?

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree, nodes

I have a binarySearch Tree and I want to create a method assignFirst.

This method should find the node in the tree with the smallest value and
update the tree's "first" attribute accordingly.

I have a lot of methods, but I don't want to include all of them in here, since I want to keep it short and simple. 
Therefore, I will include the class and some features inside that class.

```
public class BinarySearchTree<E extends Comparable<E>>
{
private BSTNode<E> root; // root of overall tree
private int numElements;
private BSTNode<E> first;
// post: constructs an empty search tree
public BinarySearchTree()
{
    this.root = null;
    this.numElements = 0;
}
private void assignFirst()
{
    if (root.left == null)
    {
        first.data = root.data;
    }
    else
        {
        first.data = root.left.data;
    }
}
public class Iterator
{
    private BSTNode<E> currentNode;

    public Iterator()
    {
        currentNode = first;
    }

    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        return currentNode != null;
    }

    public E next()
    {
        E value = currentNode.data;
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
        return value;
    }
}
private static class BSTNode<E>
{
    public E data;
    public BSTNode<E> left;
    public BSTNode<E> right;
    public BSTNode<E> parent;
    public BSTNode<E> next;

    public BSTNode(E data)
    {
        this(data, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public BSTNode(E data, BSTNode<E> left, BSTNode<E> right, BSTNode<E> parent, BSTNode<E> next)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
}
```

I updated my method look like this. I'm still uncertain if this is the correct way of doing it.

```
private void assignFirst()
{
    if (first.left != null)
    {
        first = first.left;
    }
    else
        {
        first = root;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your current `assignFirst()` method seems pretty much unrelated to the problem as you describe it.  You're modifying the data of some nodes, not setting an attribute of the tree.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I know it's incorrect, I am asking for a strategy on how to start it.

Comment: Anyway, you have a BST, and you want to identify the node carrying the smallest value.  Think about that problem for a moment.  If you start at the root node, which direction do you go to find smaller nodes?  If you're at *any* node, which direction do you go to find smaller nodes?  How do you know when you reach the node with the smallest value?

Comment: You go to the left until you can't no more. @JohnBollinger

Comment: Yes, so what's the problem with doing that?

Comment: @JohnBollinger That helps, now I'm just curious, do I do a recursion and assign that smallest value to the root?

Comment: You can locate the wanted node recursively or iteratively, it doesn't matter, but I've no idea what makes you think you'd modify the root.  Is it not the point to assign a value to member `first` of the `BinarySearchTree` object?

Comment: @JohnBollinger My bad, I would assign that to first.

Comment: Makes sense to me.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I updated my code. Let me know if its accurate

Comment: I still don't understand why you are modifying any node's *`data`*.  But in any case, I suggest you write a little test program around that so you can test whether your code works.

Comment: @JohnBollinger my bad let me change that.

Comment: It looks like you are modifying which node is the tree root.  Don't you think that will produce problems with further use of the tree?  Also, you still are not assigning anything to `first`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger what else do you suggest besides the root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I wrote it in like this.

```
private void assignFirst()
{
    BSTNode<E> node = root;
    while(node.left != null)
    {
        node = node.left;
    }
    first = node;
}
```